# How to remove a user from Discord server?

Tags: discord

I am trying to remove a user (former employee) from the list of Server Members but I am unsure how to do that (and what does the the former employee receive on their end).

The options that are shown are:

```
Mute
Change Nickname
Kick
Ban
Transfer Ownership
```

Would `Ban` be the functional equivalent of just removing a user?  Or is there a different way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kick would remove him from the server. Ban would remove him from the server and prevent him from returning with a link.

I have never been kicked or banned so I'm unsure what they would receive.

Comment: Thanks.  Both sound kind of mean...just wanted to make sure there wasn't a "nicer" option...lol! I'll kick him...but in a nice way.

Comment: The only nice way is to assertively tell them that Admin kindly requests them to leave the server.